# Content Security Policy causing 502 for WordPress admin login page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, content-security-policy

I've been setting CSP rules in my `.htaccess` for a WordPress site. At some point, something I've added causes this to happen:

- go to site.com/wp-admin to login to WordPress admin area as usual
- the page redirects to `site.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwayne.bank%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1` and displays a 502 Bad Gateway white page.
- I can then delete everything after `site.com/wp-login.php` press enter, and it loads the WordPress login, just like on wp-admin.
- I can remove all the code in `.htaccess` for `Header set Content-Security-Policy:` and it works as it should.

I've got a good amount of code in that block, and I'm not sure which part might be causing it. These are the directives set:
`frame-src`
`default-src`
`style-src`
`script-src`
`img-src`
`font-src`.

I can provide all the code if needed. What might be causing this error? Or is it simply the existence of `Header set Content-Security-Policy:` and i need to add something new inside it? I realize i can do `site.com/wp-login.php` but since there is an error, I want to fix it, especially if it could show up in other places.

Comment: The browser console should be able to tell you what part of the directive was violated, and by what. Enable the "preserve log" option so that you don't lose any information after redirects.

Comment: Thank you - I've been using console all along for CSP but did not know about the preserve log option. But, enabling that, i see this: https://snipboard.io/vzLBPH.jpg which I don't think is enough info. It's the red 502 error and in blue "Navigated to" displays the same link. So still stuck..

Comment: The `reauth=1` part in the URL seems to come from a cookie check, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90590, something going wrong with that by the looks of it. Could be due to some blocked script on the client side, dunno. If you don't see any related errors in the console, maybe enable CSP violation reporting, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP#enabling_reporting